# How to add a panel created in another class to a JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I'm currently trying to create a GUI for a game. I have a JFrame with a first panel with multiples button. After a click I'm supposed to change the panel. It works I created the first class which is a Frame

```
public class FirstWindow extends JFrame implements ActionListener
```

this class contains buttons  which make us change panels. For this I created the panels in different classes which extends JPanel. It worked but I am blocked because once in the second panels I still have to refer to other panels but I no longer have access to my initial JFrame.

To illustrate: This is how I switch from different JPanel. The "this" refers to the frame which I can't use in the other class

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      if ( "START".equals(e.getActionCommand())){
            this.setContentPane(new PanelHello());
            this.invalidate();
            this.validate();
        }else if ("EXIT".equals((e.getActionCommand()))) {
          this.dispose();
          this.invalidate();
          this.validate();
      }else if (!( usernameText.getText().equals(""))){
          this.setContentPane(new PanelHello());
          this.invalidate();
          this.validate();public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      if ( "START".equals(e.getActionCommand())){
            this.setContentPane(new PanelHello());
            this.invalidate();
            this.validate();
        }else if ("EXIT".equals((e.getActionCommand()))) {
          this.dispose();
          this.invalidate();
          this.validate();
      }else if (!( usernameText.getText().equals(""))){
          this.setContentPane(new PanelHello());
          this.invalidate();
          this.validate();
```

Comment: Use a `CardLayout` to swap panels. Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for a working example which might help you better structure your code. You don't need a reference to the frame only the panel with the CardLayout.

Comment: Also, you should NOT be using if/else statements in your ActionListener. Each button should have its own ActionListener with custom specifically related to the action for that button. Or maybe in this case you can share a single ActionListener with generic code. That is you get the "action command" from the button and then use that value to determine which panel you want to swap in the CardLayout.

Comment: @camickr I tried with anonymous and new ActionListener inside each button but it did not work. This way this way of adding the actions was the only one that worked in my code i don't know why

Comment: This forms, in part, the concepts of "delegation" and "observer" patterns.  If it was mean, I'd have some kind of "navigation controller" which would manage the core navigation.  Each panel would then provide some kind of "observer" contract that would allow the navigation controller to monitor when a change should occur and take appropriate action

Comment: Here's a [simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70009328/basic-jpanel-jframe-class-problem-in-java/70010254#70010254) of adding a `JPanel` from a different class to a `JFrame` from a recent Stack Overflow question.

Answer (score 0):

## `CardLayout`

The `CardLayout` layout manager is an extremely useful layout manager, which can be used to switch between different containers.

For me, one of its limiting factors is the need to, generally, have every container you want to switch to, instantiated and added.  This can make it "heavy", in terms of memory usage and difficult when it comes to passing information between panels - as its hard abstract the workflow, not impossible, just problematic.

One of the nice features, is till automatically determine the required size of the UI based all the other containers.

See [How to Use CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

## Custom navigation

One of the things I often finding myself needing to do, is have some kind none-linear progression through the UI, and needing the ability to effectively pass information back and forward to different containers.

The can be accomplished through the use the [delegation](http://best-practice-software-engineering.ifs.tuwien.ac.at/patterns/delegation.html), [observer pattern](http://best-practice-software-engineering.ifs.tuwien.ac.at/patterns/observer.html) and [dependency injection](http://best-practice-software-engineering.ifs.tuwien.ac.at/patterns/dependency_injection.html).

The basic principle here is, you might have a number of navigation controllers, each one managing a particular workflow, independently of all the others.  This kind of separation simplifies the needs of the application and makes it easier to move things around, should the need to be, as any one workflow isn't coupled to another.

Another aspect, which isn't demonstrated here, is the ability to return information to the navigation controller, for example, if you have a login/register workflow, the workflow could end by returning an instance of the "user" to the controller which would then be able to make determinations about which workflow they needed to go through next (admin/moderator/basic/etc)

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new MasterPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class MasterPane extends JPanel {

        private MenuPane menuPane;

        public MasterPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            presentMenu();
        }

        protected void presentMenu() {
            removeAll();

            if (menuPane == null) {
                menuPane = new MenuPane(new MenuPane.NavigationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void presentRedPane(MenuPane source) {
                        RedPane redPane = new RedPane(new ReturnNavigationListener<RedPane>() {
                            @Override
                            public void returnFrom(RedPane source) {
                                presentMenu();
                            }
                        });
                        present(redPane);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void presentGreenPane(MenuPane source) {
                        GreenPane greenPane = new GreenPane(new ReturnNavigationListener<GreenPane>() {
                            @Override
                            public void returnFrom(GreenPane source) {
                                presentMenu();
                            }
                        });
                        present(greenPane);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void presentBluePane(MenuPane source) {
                        BluePane bluePane = new BluePane(new ReturnNavigationListener<BluePane>() {
                            @Override
                            public void returnFrom(BluePane source) {
                                presentMenu();
                            }
                        });
                        present(bluePane);
                    }
                });
            }

            add(menuPane);
            revalidate();
            repaint();
        }

        protected void present(JPanel panel) {
            removeAll();
            add(panel);
            revalidate();
            repaint();
        }

    }

    public class MenuPane extends JPanel {

        public static interface NavigationListener {
            public void presentRedPane(MenuPane source);
            public void presentGreenPane(MenuPane source);
            public void presentBluePane(MenuPane source);
        }

        private NavigationListener navigationListener;

        public MenuPane(NavigationListener navigationListener) {
            this.navigationListener = navigationListener;

            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(16, 16, 16, 16));
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            JButton red = new JButton("Red");
            red.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    getNavigationListener().presentRedPane(MenuPane.this);
                }
            });
            JButton green = new JButton("Green");
            green.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    getNavigationListener().presentGreenPane(MenuPane.this);
                }
            });
            JButton blue = new JButton("Blue");
            blue.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    getNavigationListener().presentBluePane(MenuPane.this);
                }
            });

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

            add(red, gbc);
            add(green, gbc);
            add(blue, gbc);
        }

        protected NavigationListener getNavigationListener() {
            return navigationListener;
        }

    }

    public interface ReturnNavigationListener<T> {

        public void returnFrom(T source);
    }

    public class RedPane extends JPanel {

        private ReturnNavigationListener<RedPane> navigationListener;

        public RedPane(ReturnNavigationListener<RedPane> navigationListener) {
            this.navigationListener = navigationListener;
            setBackground(Color.RED);
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            add(new JLabel("Roses are red", JLabel.CENTER));

            JButton back = new JButton("Back");
            back.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    getReturnNavigationListener().returnFrom(RedPane.this);
                }
            });
            add(back, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        }

        public ReturnNavigationListener<RedPane> getReturnNavigationListener() {
            return navigationListener;
        }

    }

    public class BluePane extends JPanel {

        private ReturnNavigationListener<BluePane> navigationListener;

        public BluePane(ReturnNavigationListener<BluePane> navigationListener) {
            this.navigationListener = navigationListener;
            setBackground(Color.BLUE);
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            add(new JLabel("Violets are blue", JLabel.CENTER));

            JButton back = new JButton("Back");
            back.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    getReturnNavigationListener().returnFrom(BluePane.this);
                }
            });
            add(back, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        }

        public ReturnNavigationListener<BluePane> getReturnNavigationListener() {
            return navigationListener;
        }

    }

    public class GreenPane extends JPanel {

        private ReturnNavigationListener<GreenPane> navigationListener;

        public GreenPane(ReturnNavigationListener<GreenPane> navigationListener) {
            this.navigationListener = navigationListener;
            setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            add(new JLabel("Kermit is green", JLabel.CENTER));

            JButton back = new JButton("Back");
            back.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    getReturnNavigationListener().returnFrom(GreenPane.this);
                }
            });
            add(back, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        }

        public ReturnNavigationListener<GreenPane> getReturnNavigationListener() {
            return navigationListener;
        }

    }
}
```